# Kafka - Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, druid

Use case : Trying to integrate Kafka and Druid for the loading the data from Kafka to Druid through of KafkaClient.

When we were trying for the same, we are facing that issue . Please find the details and help me to resolve for the same .

**Issue:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:94) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:93) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:51) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:657) ~[?:?]
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

**JAAS Conf File :**

```
KafkaClient {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/hadoop_shared/net/bdnetflow.headless.keytab"
       debug=true
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       serviceName="kafka"
       principal="bdnetflow@HDP_PRD.COX.COM";
};
Client {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/hadoop_shared/net/bdnetflow.headless.keytab"
       debug=true
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       serviceName="kafka"
       principal="bdnetflow@HDP_PRD.COX.COM";
};
```

Comment: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set - This error is thrown when your client unable to find JAAS conf file. How do you start your client?

Comment: Arun - Thanks for your response   !! Could you please  share sample jaas conf file or link to refer !!

Comment: Your JAAS conf file is correct. Like I mentioned in previous comment, this error is thrown when your client unable to find JAAS conf file.